# VB.net SQL.ExecuteNonQuery

Tags: oledb, execute, oledbconnection

Currently i am trying to update the below into a database however it is returning an error message of:

> No value given for one or more required parameters.<

However i havnt set any pareters so unsure why i would need to set this:

```
    Public Sub PerformUpdates()

    'Connect to Commands DB
    Dim UpdateConn = New OleDb.OleDbConnection(Conn_string)
    UpdateConn.Open()

    Dim UpdateSQL As String = ""
    'Try
    For Each Elm As TableCommands In CommandArray

        If (Elm.ID > 0) Then
            UpdateSQL = "UPDATE tblCommands " & _
                        "SET LastCountValue='100'" & _
                        " WHERE Table_Name='dbo_AgentScore'"

            Dim sql As New OleDb.OleDbCommand(UpdateSQL, UpdateConn)
            Dim i As Integer = sql.ExecuteNonQuery

        End If
    Next
    'End Try

End Sub
```

could anyone assist with the above where i am going wrong Please?

Many Thanks,

David OConnor

Comment: Your query doesn't contain any parameter. So, probably you have mispelled some field names. Check LasCountValue and Table_Name. By the way, are you sure that the column LastCountValue is of char type?

Comment: Hi, I have confirmed that the table names /columns are spelt correctly

Comment: Additionally i have also checked that it is a Long Int field in the database however i have tried as a long (without ') and the same error appears.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: Using MS Access Database that with a table in it called tblCommands

Comment: The Sql string, expecially without the quotes around 100 is correct. Another idea: Check the connection string. Are you really working against the correct database? (It's easy to mismatch databases when you switch between debug/release builds)